# Become Sharepoint developer

Tags: development, developer

What do i need to become a Sharepoint developer?

Do i need some kind of developer license like Dynamics? Or do I just need visual studio and Sharepoint designer?

Regards Jakob

Comment: Front-End is the future, IMHO. Learn JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need an MCSE to do it, but it's kind of a weird-y niche field to get into. At this point, you should probably get to know C# (and ASP.NET in particular) and front-end web development (JS/CSS/HTML) equally and then maybe take some Pluralsight courses to learn how to make and deploy app parts, lists and libraries, and so on. There are a *lot* of things out there, too, that you can do OOB or technically OOB (because in a sense, adding JavaScript to a Script Editor that calls a SharePoint list is OOB in that you don't even necessarily need to use Designer to deploy it).

A good SharePoint developer also finds themselves wearing a variety of other hats, particularly administrator and architect. Getting in good with Powershell won't necessarily help you develop but I will say that a good 80%+ of the things that I do regarding configuration and the like, I do with a script rather than via Central Administration. You could also count straight up front end development as a different hat, as more and more people move towards solutions that have at least a client side component to them.

Answer (score 0):

You need Google.
To develop content, Visual Studio and Designer will help.  A good html and text editor will also help.
However, that is just scratching the surface.  A good understanding of (insert language here) is also crucial.
This is a very broad question.  Are you looking to do development as job or to further your SharePoint skills?

Comment: Im a C# developer with knowlage about Sharepoint. Some customers are asking about custom apps. I just cant find anything about if i need some kind of expensive developer license like Dynamics, or if i just can start develop for customer

Comment: If you can create a developer site and a app catalog site in SharePoint 2013. You have the very basic tool to develop and publish your app.

Comment: And that is what I utilize.  I have a DEV site collection that I can destroy.<br><br>You do not want to test on a live site.

Answer (score 0):

For learning purpose, you don't need any license. You need SharePoint 2010/2013 server installed. Visual Studio for Custom development like webparts and other such SharePoint components. Offcourse when you install SharePoint, you will need SQL Server, as everything in SharePoint is stored in Database.

SharePoint has different things for learning as a Developer. Like Workflows, you can use SharePoint Designer, SharePoint platform itself (Out of the box workflows) and Visual studio workflows for Custom code base workflows.

SharePoint stand alone is a single instance which is free version of SharePoint. It don't need any licensing. But if you use SharePoint server, then it has licenses like Standard and Enterprise.

Before you start any development work, you must go through the stuff that is out of the box available on internet as Guide for SharePoint. Like managing permissions, creating sites and such other stuff. So then you will have better idea that what things you can do without any development efforts and things that will need custom development tools to be used.

If you have good know how ASP.net language, then you will learn things quite easily and quickly. Further more, Javascript, jQuery, CSS, HTML etc are helpful in UI Development and front end development.